# Anonymous function in lapply (calculate distance using haversine)in R

Tags: r, dataframe, coordinates, lapply, haversine

I need to calculate the distance between the start and end coordinates using haversine function from the pracma library. I intend to use the haversine function like this:

```
distance <- haversine(c(start_lat,start_lng),c(end_lat,end_lng),R = 6371.0)
```

I need to do this for all the records available in a dataframe and store it as a column called distance within the same dataframe. A sample dataframe is given below:

```
start_lat <-  c(41.9359, 41.8604, 41.9359, 41.8969, 41.8708)
start_lng <-  c(-87.6784, -87.6258, -87.6784, -87.6217, -87.625)
end_lat <-  c(41.9493, 41.8708, 41.9171, 41.9080, 41.8708)
end_lng <-  c(-87.6463, -87.6257, -87.7102, -87.6315, -87.6257)

df <- data.frame(start_lat = start_lat,
                  start_lng = start_lng,
                  end_lat = end_lat,
                  end_lng = end_lng)
```

I am considering using lapply function to get this done.I am quite new to R and I am not able to completely understand how we can achieve this.

I tried like this:

```
df$dsitance <- lapply(df,function(x){
                     start_coord <- x[c("start_lat","start_lng")]
                     end_coord <- x[c("end_lat","end_lng")]
                     dist <- haversine(start_coord ,end_coord , R= 6371.0)
                     return(dist)})
```

I am struggling to access the data from the columns within the function. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to apply the function for every row with `lapply` you can do :

```
df$distance <- lapply(seq(nrow(df)),function(x){
        start <- unlist(df[x, c("start_lat","start_lng")])
        end <- unlist(df[x, c("end_lat","end_lng")])
        haversine(start, end, R= 6371.0)
})
```

Comment: I think the column names were incorrect in your code and data. Check the updated answer.

Comment: Thanks!! this looks good, but I am getting the following error, Error in haversine(start, end, R = 6371) : 
  Coordinate input not in correct format.  I think this is because of the argument type haversine formula is expecting, please check out the below given link I think it expects it in numerical two-vector [link]https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/pracma/versions/1.9.9/topics/haversine

Comment: @RajMohan This answer works for me for this data `df <- structure(list(start_lat = 50.0333333333333, start_lng = 8.57055555555556, end_lat = 41.9786111111111, end_lng = -87.9047222222222), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -1L))` which is in the same form.

Answer (score 2):

Easy way to do this:

```r
library(spatialrisk)
library(dplyr)

start_lat <-  c(41.9359, 41.8604, 41.9359, 41.8969, 41.8708)
start_lng <-  c(-87.6784, -87.6258, -87.6784, -87.6217, -87.625)
end_lat <-  c(41.9493, 41.8708, 41.9171, 41.9080, 41.8708)
end_lng <-  c(-87.6463, -87.6257, -87.7102, -87.6315, -87.6257)

df <- data.frame(start_lat = start_lat,
                 start_lng = start_lng,
                 end_lat = end_lat,
                 end_lng = end_lng) 

df %>%
  mutate(dist = spatialrisk::haversine(start_lat, start_lng, end_lat, end_lng))
#>   start_lat start_lng end_lat  end_lng       dist
#> 1   41.9359  -87.6784 41.9493 -87.6463 3047.88841
#> 2   41.8604  -87.6258 41.8708 -87.6257 1157.75239
#> 3   41.9359  -87.6784 41.9171 -87.7102 3363.98884
#> 4   41.8969  -87.6217 41.9080 -87.6315 1478.54766
#> 5   41.8708  -87.6250 41.8708 -87.6257   58.02598
```

<sup>Created on 2021-05-16 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Or without the use of `dplyr::mutate()`:

```
df$dist <- spatialrisk::haversine(df$start_lat, df$start_lng, 
                                  df$end_lat, df$end_lng)
```

<sup>Created on 2021-05-16 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Comment: I got the following error Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `dist`.
x unused argument (end_lng)
i Input `dist` is `haversine(start_lat, start_lng, end_lat, end_lng)`., does haversine accept argument directly like start_lat, start_lng, end_lat, end_lng ?I haven't used it before

Comment: I updated my answer. Does this solve the error?

Comment: Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `dist`.
x there is no package called ‘spatialrisk’
i Input `dist` is `spatialrisk::haversine(start_lat, start_lng, end_lat, end_lng)`.                       I tried require("spatialrisk")as well got the following msg , Loading required package: spatialrisk
Warning message:
In library(package, lib.loc = lib.loc, character.only = TRUE, logical.return = TRUE,  :
  there is no package called ‘spatialrisk’

Comment: You should first install the package: `install.packages("spatialrisk")`

Comment: Thanks this works! Is the output in kms or miles?

Comment: Distance is in meters